# A question on Rational numbers in simplest form

Tags: number-theory

A function $f(x)$ is defined $\forall x \in \mathbb{Q}$ and $ x \in (0,1)$ as $f(x) = q $ where $x = (p/q)$ in simplest form. Find $\sup_{\tau} \quad \min_{a} \quad f(a) + f(\tau-a)$    where $ a \in \mathbb{Q}$ and $ a \in (0,1)$ and $ \tau \in (\alpha,\beta)$ where   $ 0< \alpha < \beta <2 $ and $ \alpha,\beta \in \mathbb{Q} $. $\sup$ and $\min$ are taken over only those $x$ where $f(x)$ is defined. Is the supremum infinity ?

**EDIT**

The supremum may or may not depend on $\alpha$ and $\beta$...this has not been ruled out.

---

**EDIT 2**

I will try something !

Consider $\tau = l/m$ where $l,m \in \mathbb{N}$ in simplest form and $\tau \in \mathbb{Q}\cap(0,2)$.

what is minimum possible value of $q$ where $\tau-a = p/q $ written in simplest form
such that $a \in \mathbb{Q} \cap (0,1)$ and $(\tau-a) \in (0,1)$.

As Yuval Filmus suggested in his answer...

one way to choose $a$ is that it has same denominator (in simplest form) as that of $\tau$ and numerator $n$ such that $l-n$ is relatively prime to $m$, (If such a choice is possible under given conditions), then $f(a)+f(\tau-a)$ becomes $2m$.

**The question is whether such a choice leading to $f(a)+f(\tau-a) = 2m$ is the minimum possible value ? If not I request you to give a counter example.**

If it is, then the supremum (over $\tau$ varying in any arbitrary open interval contained in $(0,2)$) is $\infty$ as we can increase $m$ arbitrarily by varying $\tau$ in any arbitrary open interval $(\alpha,\beta)$.

**EDIT 3**

**small change in Question...instead of** $0<\alpha<\beta<2$ we have $-1<\alpha<\beta<1$

**this change is not made with any intention of bringing out a certain solution.Also its influence on the solution is hoped to be very small.Inconvenience is regretted.**

Comment: For questions like this, it is nice to give some indication of what you have tried so far and where you got stuck.

Comment: Even though i have formulated the question...every time i attempt to solve I get lost and tend to move away from the actual question. I find it hard to get hold of anything in it !

Comment: I badly need some help atleast to get started somewhere

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT: This is a consolidated solution which previously appeared in parts.

Lemma 1. For each natural $M$ and real $\alpha < \beta$ there's a rational number in $(\alpha,\beta)$ whose reduced form has a denominator larger than $M$.

Proof. Choose some power of two $2^n > \max\left(M, \frac{2}{\beta-\alpha}\right)$. Since $2^{-n} < \frac{\beta-\alpha}{2}$, there are at least two fractions of the form $x/2^n$ in $(\alpha,\beta)$. One of them has odd $x$ and so is in reduced form.

Lemma 2. If $p_1/q_1 + p_2/q_2 = P/Q$, all rationals in reduced form, then $(q_1+q_2)^2 \geq 4Q$.

Proof. Taking a common denominator, $\frac{p_1 q_2 + p_2 q_1}{q_1q_2} = \frac{P}{Q}$ and so $Q|q_1q_2$ (since $P/Q$ is reduced). In particular $Q \leq q_1q_2 \leq \left(\frac{q_1+q_2}{2}\right)^2$, where the last inequality is the arithmetic-geometric mean inequality.

Theorem. For every real $M$ and reals $\alpha < \beta$ there is a rational $r \in (\alpha,\beta)$ such that $\min_{a \in \mathbb{Q}} f(a) + f(r-a) > M$.

Proof. Using lemma 1, take a rational $r \in (\alpha,\beta)$ with denominator $Q > M^2/4$. Using lemma 2, we conclude that for every rational $a$, $f(a) + f(r-a) \geq 2\sqrt{Q} = M$.

Corollary. $$\sup_r \min_a f(a) + f(r-a) = \infty.$$

Comment: @Yuval Filmus: ....what is B ? a natural number ? why is q1+q2 being considered here ?

Comment: @Yuval Filmus: $P = 1$ and $Q = q_1q_2$ ?? please confirm

Comment: @Yuval Filmus: using the property that when $p,q$ are relatively prime then there exist $x,y \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $px+qy = 1$.

Comment: @Yuval Filmus: I am not able to make out how it leads me to answer the question.

Comment: B is a real number, it corresponds to the supremum.

Comment: Can you say anything about the denominator of $p_1/q_1 + p_2/q_2$?

Comment: @Yuval Filmus: The Supremum could only be an integer if it exists.

Comment: @Yuval Filmus: $p,q$ in the question are integers.

Comment: @Yuval Filmus: cant say anything about denominator of $p_1/q_1 + p_2/q_2$ in general.

Comment: Can using a common denominator help?

Comment: @Yuval Filmus: yes in that case $q_1+q_2 = 2Q >B$ but how does that help in answering the current question ?

Comment: @Yuval Filmus: I mean not getting the point !

Comment: @Yuval Filmus: Please let me know if there is any ambiguity in the question. The function $f(x)$ is defined only for $\mathbb{Q}$ lying in (0,1). The function $f\colon \mathbb{Q}\to \mathbb{N}$.

Comment: @Yuval Filmus: earlier I couldn't realize that you have started off with $\tau = a+(\tau-a)$ (nevertheless it being not mentioned). That is what making your proof look stunningly simple ! I made a mistake by trying to choose $a = a_{min}$ directly and got lost in the details. Thank you for the proof !

Comment: @Yuval Filmus: I request you to make the answer more readable even for a person who has'nt made any attempt at the solution.This way it would be more helpful for any reader.

Answer (score 1):

For a given $\tau=\frac{1}{q}, q$ prime it seems that $a$ should be (perhaps among other choices) $\frac{\tau}{2}$ with $\sup_{\tau} \quad \min_{a} \quad f(a) + f(\tau-a)=2q$.  Can you prove this?  If so, then the sup over $\tau$ is infinity as you can find $\tau$ with arbitrarily large denominator.

Comment: the supremum is over $\tau$ varying in any arbitrary open interval contained in (-1,1). It should be proven for every arbitrary open interval contained in (-1,1). Hence the assumption that the numerator of $\tau$ (in simplest form) being equal to $1$ may not cover all possibilities.

Comment: You are right.  I think the same argument can be made for any $\tau=\frac{p}{q}$ with $q$ prime.  The frightening thing is for $\frac{1}{n(n+1)}$, where $\frac{1}{n}$ and $\frac{1}{n+1}$ work for a sum of 2n+1.  Even that goes to infinity with $\tau$, but only as the square root.